# How to turn an object properties into coulmns in spring jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

So I have an entity class where one of its properties is another object. How can I make spring jpa turn that class's properties into columns just like the properties of my entity class?

I have tried to make that object's class into an entity but didn't know how I can include it in my first class.

Comment: Done a little research found out that All I had to do was just using @Embedded Anotation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `@Embeddable` and `@Embedded`. Use this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-embedded-embeddable) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

if class MsgDetail has a field: Msg, then add @Entity and @Table on Msg.